# Is it possible to use Pupeteer to render a template (ejs) for local development, (hot reloading) in Nest.js?

Tags: json, nestjs, puppeteer

I am using a local Nest app to generate a PDF with Pupeteer, EJS with postman. What I would like is to have a route in the same app which when you go to the browser and do something like:

```
localhost:8016/renderTemplate
```

That route is consuming some local `.json` in a folder which would be data for the template **AND** I can edit the `.ejs` and see the changes hot reload in the browser.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as data from './json/index.json'
import * as ejs from 'ejs';
import puppeteer, { Browser, Page } from 'puppeteer';


@Injectable()
export class RenderPayloadToBrowserService {

    /**
     * Uses Puppeteer to generate a template in the browser and have hot reloading
     *
     * @return {*}  {Promise<Buffer>}
     */
     async renderPayload(): Promise<Buffer> {
        try {
            const content: string = ejs.render(Buffer.from(file.buffer).toString(), { data });

            const browser: Browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
               headless: true, 
               ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
               args: ['--no-sandbox'] 
            });
            const page: Page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setContent(content);

            const buffer: Buffer = await page;

            await browser.close();

            return buffer;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck at this line:

```
 const content: string = ejs.render(Buffer.from(file.buffer).toString(), { data });
```

What I want is to pass the .ejs in there as the template, but when I try to import the file i don’t see `index.ejs` as an option.

Also the `buffer` variable is complaining I just don't know which props it needs.

Can this be done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see the `index.ejs`"?

Comment: @ggorlen I meant I don’t see it in intelliisense as a option.